# how to use underscore .reduce to return and object that counts properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

considering

```
   var desserts = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter' ],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Strawberry-Rhubarb Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'strawberries', 'rhubarb'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lemonade',
    ingredients: ['water', 'sugar', 'lemons'],
    type: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Chip Cookies',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'butter', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'chocolate chips'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Angel Food Cake',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cake'
  }
];
```

I am trying to use underscore reduce to output and object that counts how many of each type there are

```
{'pie' : 3, 'cake' : 2}...
```

Here is what I have so far

```
var dessertCategories = function (desserts) {
  return _.reduce(desserts, function(memo, dessert) {
    var type1 = dessert.type;
    if (memo[type1] === undefined) {
      memo[type1] = 1;
    } else {
      memo[type1]++;
    }
    return memo;
  }, {});
};
```

I believe I am using reduce incorrectly here or it may be my logic. I am trying to follow the template from underscore.

Comment: If this is all your code, then your code is not actually calling the function you've created called `dessertCategories`. Instead it has created a function named `dessertCategories` that you have to call.

Comment: [It works correctly](https://jsbin.com/quxubiwuvu/1/edit) what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue, I think, is that you are not calling the `dessertCategories` function you've made anywhere.

The below gets you there. If you'd like to have `dessertCategories` be the map of categories->counts then remove the outer `function(){...}` wrapper.

```js
var desserts = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter' ],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Strawberry-Rhubarb Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'strawberries', 'rhubarb'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lemonade',
    ingredients: ['water', 'sugar', 'lemons'],
    type: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Chip Cookies',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'butter', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'chocolate chips'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Angel Food Cake',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cake'
  }
];
// Mock underscore implementation, ignore it.
var _ = {reduce: (arr, fn, init) => Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, fn, init)}

var dessertCategories = function (desserts) {
  return _.reduce(desserts, function(memo, dessert) {
    var type1 = dessert.type;
    if (memo[type1] === undefined) {
      memo[type1] = 1;
    } else {
      memo[type1]++;
    }
    return memo;
  }, {});
};
// Actually calling the function you've created.
console.info(dessertCategories(desserts));
```

Answer (score 1):

Several others have pointed out that your code is essentially correct; you just need to call the function that you defined. Alternatively, you could omit the outer `function` wrapper and assign the result of `_.reduce` directly to `dessertCategories`:

```js
var dessertCategories = _.reduce(desserts, function(memo, dessert) {
  var type1 = dessert.type;
  if (memo[type1] === undefined) {
    memo[type1] = 1;
  } else {
    memo[type1]++;
  }
  return memo;
}, {});
```

However, for this particular purpose, there is actually an easier function than `_.reduce`: [`_.countBy`](https://underscorejs.org/#countBy). Please see it demonstrated below.

```js
var desserts = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter' ],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Strawberry-Rhubarb Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'strawberries', 'rhubarb'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lemonade',
    ingredients: ['water', 'sugar', 'lemons'],
    type: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Chip Cookies',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'butter', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'chocolate chips'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Angel Food Cake',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cake'
  }
];

var dessertCategories = _.countBy(desserts, 'type');
console.info(dessertCategories);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic for loop and Map

```js
var desserts = [{
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter'],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Strawberry-Rhubarb Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'strawberries', 'rhubarb'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lemonade',
    ingredients: ['water', 'sugar', 'lemons'],
    type: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Chip Cookies',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'butter', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'chocolate chips'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Apple Pie',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'water', 'cinnamon', 'apples', 'sugar'],
    type: 'pie'
  },
  {
    name: 'Angel Food Cake',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cake'
  }
];
let map = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < desserts.length; i++) {
    if (!map.has(desserts[i].type)) {
        map.set(desserts[i].type, 0);
    }
    map.set(desserts[i].type, map.get(desserts[i].type) + 1)
}
console.log(map.entries())
```